# Windows Workflow Foundation 3 wait inside parallel activity

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-3

I have a workflow where the order of execution for the activities is:

- codeActivity1
- codeActivity2
- codeActivity3
- codeActivity4
- codeActivity5
- codeActivity6
- codeActivity8
- codeActivity7

The rule which wwf uses is obviously that activities of each branch get executed in turns. This is ok for me for most of my activities with one exception: I have one activity in the first branch that needs to execute before the activities of second branch.  I know I can just put the activities of the second branch before this one activity, but that would make my existing workflows harder to understand. Each branch has activities which work on some areas of my application.

I am looking for some kind of "waiting activity" that does not execute until some condition is met. The important part is that id does not pause the current thread, because that would not allow the activities of the first branch to continue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly I would use either While activity or ConditionedActivityGroup activity, which can wait until some condition is met, then continue.

Comment: I went with the whileActivity and it is exactly what I need